# Searchable Dropdown list in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlConnection myDBCon = new SqlConnection(sc); 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select  Caption_name from Commercial_caption", myDBCon);
myDBCon.Open();
SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
mySqlAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
mySqlAdapter.Fill(ds);
DropDownList1.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Caption_name";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--","0"));
myDBCon.Close();
```

Comment: i just binded my drop downlist with data in mysql!

Comment: checked already sir, but i want to do in c sharp hard coding.

Comment: yes, but i am fetching my 580 records from database

Comment: I have posted my answer let me know if t does not work for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Select2` `The jQuery replacement for select boxes`. First include these files and you can download them from [Here](https://github.com/select2/select2)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**ASP**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="custom" AutoPostBack="true">   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Java Script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#DropDownList1").select2({
            placeholder: "Select an option",
            allowClear: true
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Custom **CSS** for increasing the width of `DropDownList`

```
<style type="text/css">
   .custom 
   {
       width: 50%;
   }
</style>
```

Your code behind logic remains the same. I have tested it and its working fine.

**Code Behind**

```
SqlConnection myDBCon = new SqlConnection(sc); 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select  Caption_name from Commercial_caption", myDBCon);
myDBCon.Open();
SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
mySqlAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
mySqlAdapter.Fill(ds);
DropDownList1.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Caption_name";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("",""));
myDBCon.Close();
```

**Note:**  You need to add an empty item at 0th index and `select2` have option for placeholder.

Comment: oh, ty so much, i will just check into.

Comment: i does not work for me because i cant make out which file to download and how should i add it to my project

Comment: @shahzeb khan you should learn it than this platform is not for consultancy. You post your issue and you get an answer and if you post it like how can I add files you will definitely get down votes. Google is here for your every question. Give it a try. Good luck :)

Comment: but i cant find the this file "js/jquery-3.1.1.js" in the select2 zip folder

Comment: check `dist` folder

Comment: i dont see any file by that name, so how should i find it!

Comment: and i cant write to search on dropdown list , as i click it just show me the list of menus from database

Comment: did you include my written JS Code

Comment: yes, i did , i added select2.js file in my project but i could not find the other file jquer-3.1.1.js

Comment: i have added it do everything but does not allow me to search in the dropdown llist from database, is something wrong with my code or what?

Comment: lets continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net

Comment: is something wrong in the code? i dont see th input box to chat at the boottom if the link you sent me @Afnana Ahmad